# How would you solve the inequality $\sin x \gt \cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$\sin x \gt \cos x, \qquad (-2\pi <x <2\pi)$$

I tried an approach saying that $\tan x\gt1$ but apparently the solution, which is $\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{5\pi}{4}$ is not good.

It's a bit confusing.

Comment: (1) Look at he trigonometric (unit) circle. The answer there is trivial. (2) Expand the result periodically $\;2\pi\;$ .

Comment: you have to mention in which interval this is

Comment: interval between -2pi and 2pi. I tried it and my answer is pi/4<x<5pi/4

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't really get it. Why can't I use tan(x)>1 and solve?

Comment: Because $\tan$ loses sign information important to the question.

Comment: That assumes $\cos x>0$. If $\cos x<0$, you get $\tan x<1$. Remember what happens if you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative.

Comment: @DavidMitra So, I can't just assume that cosx is positive? Another approach I tried is let sinx=cosx, then I solved for x saying that tanx = 1. I got 2 values for x and then I drew the graph to see where they intersect and got the answer. But I don't know why this works and tanx>1 doens't.

Comment: That would give you the solution in the case that $\cos x>0$. You'd still need to consider the case when $\cos x<0$. Also, you would need to check the case when $\cos x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

First look at where $\sin x = \cos x$ (the unit circle will be of help).

Here is the unit circle available at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg). The ordered pairs along the circumference correspond to $\;(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$

[image]

There are two such solutions $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 2\pi]$: $\;\pi/4, 5\pi/4$. $\sin (\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4) = 1/2,\;$ and $\;\sin(5\pi/4) = \cos (5\pi/4) = -1/2$.

That will give you *intervals* to check for when $\sin x > \cos x$.  It looks like given your comment below your answer that you correctly found when $\sin x > \cos x$ on the interval $x\in [0, 2\pi]$!

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti, for letting me know (and not embarrassing me at said post!) I'll delete my answer. Why not post your solution? I'm quite sure the OP will appreciate it, and since you put all that work into it, I'd love to see your post.

Answer (score 2):

Draw (or plot) a picture and take the $2\pi$ periodicity into account.

[image]

Comment: excuse me! I don't know how to insert graphical resentations , can you suggest me ?

Comment: (+1) for the idea of plotting both functions, but (-1) for putting numbers on the $x$-axis instead of multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @mahavir: When you edit an answer, some icon/buttons appear over the edit window. The 6th from the left allows you to enter an image.

Comment: @TMM That means 0, right?

Answer (score 1):

First split the problem in 4 sub-problems regarding each interval.

Reduce every angle to a respective angle in the first quadrant. Then find the angle where both values have same value and use the fact that sine is increasing, while cosine is decreasing function in the first quadrant.

Another way is to shift one angle by 90, and use one well known trigonometric identity:

$$\sin(x)>\cos(x) = \sin(90 -x)$$
$$\sin(x) - \sin(90 - x) >0$$
$$2\sin(x - 45)\cos(45) > 0$$

Now just find when $\sin(x-45) > 0$

Your idea is good, but you don't applied it well, since when you divide by a negative number the sign changes.

Comment: The last method(using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) is what I like the best and was going add that:)

Answer (score 1):

Over the interval $−2\pi < x < 2\pi$, $\cos x$ as well as $\sin x$ can have negative values. $\tan x>1$ would be good approach for finding $|\sin x|>|\cos x|$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the [trigonometric circle](https://www.google.com/search?q=TRIGONOMETRIC+CIRCLE&espv=210&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=FyuDfKO6GiIszM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcQpKgUsFa6IqNq0NtXdFnviTVRz6Fvg6o1Z7oUr0w9msawdV9Fa%253B2012%253B1772%253BCUoZ1BIvBMwHfM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.geocities.ws%25252Fpetrinamaher%25252FFST.html&source=iu&usg=__lFIridQShCYd-yXS7yemhHny8RI%3D&sa=X&ei=25slU53VD-aa4wTDwoC4CQ&ved=0CC0Q9QEwAg#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=U1c4Wrx4eq-s2M%253A%3BtObXnu14ep31nM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdpmathematicssl.weebly.com%252Fuploads%252F1%252F2%252F6%252F8%252F12680071%252F2763336_orig.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdpmathematicssl.weebly.com%252Ftopic-3---circular-functions-and-trigonometry.html%3B400%3B345).

At each point on the circle, the $\;y$-coordinate denotes the value of sine, and the $\;x$- coordinate the value of cosine, and since you've edited your question and you *only* want the values in the circle and its negative for which the inequality is true, the diagram *almost-almost*  gives you the complete answer...

Algebraically:

$$\text{For}\;\;x\ge 0:\;\;\;\sin x>\cos x\iff\begin{cases}\frac\pi4<x<\frac{3\pi}4&,\;\;\text{or}\\{}\\
\pi<x<\frac{5\pi}4&,\;\;\text{or}\\{}\\
\frac{7\pi}4<x<2\pi\end{cases}$$

Now, what to do with $\;x<0\;$ ? Well, that's for you now to figure out using that

$$x<0\implies -x>0\;,\;\;\sin(-x)=-\sin x\;,\;\;\cos(-x)=\cos x\ldots$$

Answer (score -1):

for $$0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}, \qquad \sin x<\cos x$$ and  for  $$\frac{\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}, \qquad \sin x>\cos x$$

Comment: This only covers a quarter of a circle...

Comment: ...and it does not explain why those inequalities hold.